# Cell with 2 values. Display 1 and hide the other

Tags: excel

my problem is that I have created a drop down menu in Excel with various values. Now to reference these cells in further cells, I want to assign values to the selected values of drop down.

Eg:
If I select 'YES' in the drop down at cell A1, the value of cell A1 should be changed to 0 but still display 'YES'. Is this possible?

Comment: How about setting a new cell's value based on the results of the drop-down? E.g., `B1` `=IF(A1="YES",0,1)`

Answer (score 1):

you can use a Custom Number Format `"NO";;"YES"`. Then it should show `YES` for 0 and `NO` for 1.

Each format is divided in sections: `<POSITIVE>;<NEGATIVE>;<ZERO>;<TEXT>`
, for more information see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264372/en

Comment: technically it would be YES for 0, and NO for every positive number ;-) but it'd fit for your problem yet.